# Raw DML doesn't work using sqlalchemy in Python 3.10.9

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a sqlite DB on my local PC
I have below SQL to run:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import text

db = r"c:\data\my.db"
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(f"sqlite:///{db}", echo=False)
sql = r"delete from users where id = '123456'"
with engine.connect() as con:
    statement = text(sql)
    con.execute(statement)
close_engine(engine)
```

It doesn't populate any error message but the user id 123456 was not deleted.
Can someone please advise the potential reason? Thanks in advance

Here's my environment:
Python 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
sqlalchemy 2.0.9

Comment: I see! In old version(1.4) it said: 
Given this requirement, SQLAlchemy implements its own “autocommit” feature which works completely consistently across all backends. This is achieved by detecting statements which represent data-changing operations, i.e. INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, as well as data definition language (DDL) statements such as CREATE TABLE, ALTER TABLE, and then issuing a COMMIT automatically if no transaction is in progress.
While in the new version(2.0) this autocommit has been deprecated! Thanks for the help